# Limitar número de linhas da segunda tabela?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Olá, boa noite!

Possuo duas tabelas (Processo e Andamentos). Preciso de gerar um relatório com os dados do Processo, junto com o andamento mais recente. A query que escrevi está me retornando todos os andamentos, fazendo repetir os dados dos processos. Já tentei usar `$this->db->limit(1)` mas assim, só me retorna 1 único processo de vários que devem aparecer.

Query na Classe Model_Processo:

```
function get_processos_ativos() {        
        $this->db->join('andamento', 'fkcodprocesso=codprocesso', 'left'); 
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->order_by("str_to_date(andamento.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y')", 'DESC', FALSE);
        return $this->db->get('processo')->result();
    }
```

Código da View:

```
<?php foreach ($processo as $proc) : ?>
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-4" >                         
            <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica"><strong>Autos nº:</strong> <a href="<?= base_url('processo/processoclicked/' . $proc->codprocesso) ?>" target="_self"><font size="2" face="helvetica"><?php echo $proc->nprocesso; ?></font></a></strong></font></p>                         
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica"><strong>Comarca:</strong> <?php echo $proc->comarca; ?> - <?php echo $proc->numerovara; ?> <?php echo $proc->vara; ?></font></p> 
        </div>      
    </div>   
    <!-- ...vários outros dados da tabela processo. -->


    Aqui é o dado onde eu quero que só apresente o último registro da tabela Andamentos:    

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"    >                        
            <p align="justify"><font  size="2" face="helvetica"><strong>Último Andamento:</strong> <?php echo $proc->dtandamento; ?> - <?php echo $proc->descricao; ?></font></p>
        </div>  
    </div>                                             
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Qual a query que está a usar para obter os dados da base de dados? Penso que a solução passará mais facilmente pela consulta do que propriamente pelo código PHP.

Comment: @JoãoMartins no momento essa aí de cima, que me trás todos os andamentos de cada processo, ocorre que eu preciso somente do último registro da tabela andamentos: 

function get_processos_ativos() {        
        $this->db->join('andamento', 'fkcodprocesso=codprocesso', 'left'); 
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->order_by("str_to_date(andamento.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y')", 'DESC', FALSE);
        return $this->db->get('processo')->result();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Se o teu objectivo e apenas limitar os resultados sem mais nenhuma condição estavas no caminho certo sendo que deves usar

`$this->db->limit(N)` sendo `N` o numero de linhas que queres apresentar

Comment: então @NunoMaximiano deixa eu explicar melhor, 1 Processo possuii vários andamentos, ocorre que eu preciso exibir vários processos e o último andamento de cada um, quando eu utilizo o $this->db->limit(1); ele só me retorna um único registo, no caso um único processo, sendo q preciso exibir vários processos. Deu p entender?

Comment: Acho que já percebi o problema
para conseguires resolver esse problema vais ter ter usar sub-queries em vez de join

`$this->db->select('p.*, (select a.campo_a_apresentar from andamento a where a.idProcesso = p.id limit 1) AS campo_a_Apresentar ');
$this->db->order_by("str_to_date(andamento.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y')", 'DESC', FALSE);
$this->db->from('processo p');
return $this->db->get()->result();`

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno, mas parece que o CodeIgniter 3.x não aceita mais Subqueries??